# How to put data into table according to category.

Tags: php, mysql

I want to put the data into a table according to the $category row. So, there would be multiple tables, with each table containing only items that have the same $category.

I've been stuck on this for a while, so any help would be great!

Thanks in advance!

```
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    $rows[] = $row;
}

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $food = $row["food"];
    $price = $row["price"];
    $picture = $row["picture"];
    $id = $row['id'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $category = $row['category'];

    echo "<tr>
           <td><img src='uploads/$picture' width='120px' height='120'/></td>
           <td><div><span>$food</span></div></td>
           <td><div><span>$$price</span></div></td>
           <td><div><span><input type='number' min='0' max='10' placeholder='#' name='qty[".$id."]' maxlength='1'></span></div></td>
           <td><div><span><i>$description</i></span></div></td>
          </tr>";
        } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $food = $row["food"];
    $price = $row["price"];
    $picture = $row["picture"];
    $id = $row['id'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $category = $row['category'];

    $categoryRow = "<tr>
           <td><img src='uploads/$picture' width='120px' height='120'/></td>
           <td><div><span>$food</span></div></td>
           <td><div><span>$$price</span></div></td>
           <td><div><span><input type='number' min='0' max='10' placeholder='#' name='qty[".$id."]' maxlength='1'></span></div></td>
           <td><div><span><i>$description</i></span></div></td>
          </tr>";
    $categoryRows[$category] = $categoryRows[$category] . $categoryRow;
}
foreach($categoryRows as $categoryTitle=>$tableRows){

    echo "<h2>$categoryTitle</h2><table>$tableRows</table>";

}
```

Comment: Updated with request.